# How to only copy the exact index element from a string array?

Tags: c++

I am working on this code, and got confused..
How to only get the 10th element and above only to be copied into the buffer?

For example, I have this string "http://www.google.com". I don't want the "http://www." part to be copied inside my `testDest` buffer.

```
  char testDest[256];
  char *p= _com_util::ConvertBSTRToString(URL->bstrVal);

  for (int i = 0; i <= strlen(p); i++)    
  {
    testDest[i] = p[i];   
  }
```

Comment: What buffer? A `char *`?

Comment: Are you asking how to find the starting point for the copy operation? If not, for this simple case you can just copy the `google.com` portion by using `strcpy(testDest, p + 11);` (note: unsafe C code with no error checking).

Comment: any way to only grep the hostname address without getting the http/https protocol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't do this by counting. What if the next address is https://www. or if the link doesn't even have a www in it? For things like this, your best friend is "Pattern Matching".

But if you really know what you're doing, just let your for-loop begin at 10 instead of zero:

```
for (int i = 9; i <= strlen(p); i++)
{
    testDest[i-9] = p[i];
}
```

Also, this isn't really C++ what you're doing. C++ has much nicer alternatives than using char buffers. Just saying :)

Comment: You are right. I'm currently try to figure out how to handle either it is http or https?